# No enum constant in build.gradle

Tags: android, testing, gradle

I'm trying to run todo-mvp of google samples but it gives me this error:

```
Error:(55, 0) No enum constant org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.SKİPPED
```

I don't have experience with testing and don't know gradle proficiently. What might be the cause?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Changing my computer's language to English solved the problem. But not cool Gradle, not cool. You shouldn't take locale into account in this scenerio.

Answer (score 2):

Changing computer's language is solution but if you don't want to change your language here is alternative solution :

```
// Always show the result of every unit test, even if it passes.
testOptions.unitTests.all {
    testLogging {
        events 'passed', 'SKIPPED', 'FAILED', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
    }
}
```

I see this solution on there : [TestLogEvent](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/logging/TestLogEvent.html) and I realized we can use uppercase letters.

As you can see the problem is **i** character, since there is no **İ** character in English you need to convert them to **I**. I come to this idea from my logcat :

```
No enum constant org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.SKİPPED
```